# ajax call not sending data correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

There is something wrong with the way I am using the ajax call.

When I place the ajax call inside the block, it executes the error function in the ajax callback. When the ajax call is moved outside the block, the variable **subcate** passed  to server is undefined.

```
var that = this;
var subCate ='' ;
var tr = $('#tbl').find('tr');

//My block
tr.bind('click', function(event) {
    var values = '';
    tr.removeClass('highlight');
    var tds = $(this).addClass('highlight').find('td');
    subCate = tds.find('#myid').text();
    alert(subCate);


      //Tried moving it out of the block but not much of help
        $.ajax({
            url: '/playground',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { id: subCate},
            success: function(data){
                alert("Sub category recvd");
                console.log("successs");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR){
                console.log("failed");
                alert("failed");
            }
        });
    });

    //Ajax call moved here
```

Here is the node.js server code :

```
  app.post('/playground', function(req, res) {
        debug("Inside post(/playground) ",req.body.id);
        res.send('ok', 200);
    });
```

Hi Here is the snippet of HTML table, that will give an idea what the jquery code is doing

```
<div id="category-container">
      <div id="category-form">
        <h1></h1>
        <p id="sub1" class="subheading">Select a category</p>
        <!--hr-->
        <div style="margin:20px" class="container">
          <table id="tbl" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <!--th(style='width:40px') #-->
                <th style="width:180px">Name</th>
                <th style="width:200px">Location</th>
                <th style="width:180px">Username</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div id="myid"><a id="item" href="/playground/:0">Electronics</a></div>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div id="myid"><a id="item" href="/playground/:1">Real Estate</a></div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance guys !

Comment: Why are you using .find() to select an element by id? shouldn't id's be unique?

Comment: What does the `alert(subCate);` show?  Do you have a value there or is it undefined at that point already?

Comment: If you post a sample of the HTML that this jQuery is trying to call into it would be a big help.  Is it possible that there are just no matches when you call  `tds.find('#myid')`?

Comment: Hi The alert(subCate) is working. I have tested that.

Comment: If you move the call outside and pass a hardcode value instead of your variable, does it work?

Comment: Your markup is invalid.  It is, and HAS been since the 1999 4.0 html specification, invalid to have duplicate ID's in your markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `event.preventDefault()` at the top of your bind.

Also, I recommend changing the event binding to the following:

```
$('#tbl').on('click', 'tr', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // your code
});
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. The event.preventDefault call has fixed the problem.